# Web component: How to query children of a slot

Tags: web-component

Say I have a native web component, and it has a slot:

```html
    <slot id="CONTENT_SLOT" name="content"></slot>
```

`const CONTENT_SLOT = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("CONTENT_SLOT")` finds the element, but `CONTENT_SLOT.children` is empty.

`this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('[slot="content"]')` returns an empty node list too.

`document.querySelectorAll('[slot="content"]')` finds items in the slot, but for all web components.

How can I get a NodeList of the elements in the `content` slot for the current web component instance only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the elements that are assigned to the slot with [`assignedElements()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedElements).

```js
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#CONTENT_SLOT').assignedElements();
```

The difference between doing this and `this.querySelectorAll('[slot="content"]')` is that you get the elements that are actually in the slot instead the elements who have the `slot` attribute. Elements that aren't a direct child of the custom-element and do have the attribute will not be in the `<slot>`, but they will be found with `this.querySelectorAll('[slot="content"]')`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```js
this.querySelectorAll('[slot="content"]')
```